# Hardware incompatibility with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation

Is it possible that some hardware cannot support the Ubuntu 18.04? I have the following specs in my PC, and I was told that the installation of Ubuntu 18.04 failed because the hardware doesn't support this version, but it did not give errors when Ubuntu 20.04 was installed.

- TR Pro 3955WX 3.9G 16C
- 4x32GB DDR4 3200 RDIMM
- 2x 1TB M.2 2280 NVMe3x4 TLC OP
- 2x 10TB HDD
- 1x Quadro RTX4000 8GB 3DP+VL(LE)

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu has both products that use the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 18) and products that use the *year.month* format (eg. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). They are different products; the *year* products are intended for *headless* devices, appliances or cloud use for example; so it maybe not what you intended when you said Ubuntu 18 (there is no Ubuntu 18 product; but the 18 implies a *snap* only specialist release)

Comment: Maybe the 1x Quadro RTX4000 8GB 3DP+VL(LE) which was released in 2019 is not compatible with Ubuntu 18.04, but it is compatible with Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Also note - if you're comparing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using the HWE kernel stack (eg. 18.04.5 media) then it's the same kernel stack as found in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (using the original GA kernel; ie. before update).  You didn't say which *kernel stack* option you're using; as LTS releases have two options (GA for stability; HWE for later kernel modules (ie. *drivers*))  Six different ISOs are available for 18.04 Desktop with four different kernel options at install time (but after update they'll either be GA or HWE) so which you used may provide some clues

Comment: @karel I can find instructions for installation of the driver so I guess, it should not be a problem https://tutorialforlinux.com/2019/08/27/how-to-install-nvidia-quadro-rtx4000-ubuntu-18-04-driver/

Comment: @guiverc I am talking about the 18.04 LTS and 20-04 LTS- I have no idea about the kernel options, as it was not me doing the installation. I guess I can find out the kernel used in the currently installed 20.04 version.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is rather *vague*, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server for example defaults to the GA stack for any ISO/media; where as Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop & 18.04.1 Desktop default to GA, however 18.04.2 through 18.04.5 Desktop media default to HWE kernel; but you didn't provide details of what media you installed with (*thus we cannot know your 18.04 stack*). Ubuntu 18.04 with HWE media is the same kernel & stack as found in Ubuntu 20.04 with GA stack; which is not the case if you compare Ubuntu 18.04 with GA and Ubuntu 20.04 with HWE stack.  Specifics help us to understand & help you more...

Answer (score 3):

The [How to Install Nvidia Quadro 4000 Ubuntu 18.04 Driver](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2019/08/27/how-to-install-nvidia-quadro-rtx4000-ubuntu-18-04-driver/2/) tutorial that you linked to in your comment is already not up-to-date for Ubuntu 18.04, so I think it can be improved a little bit. The nvidia-driver-465 package has already been added to the default Ubuntu 18.04 repositories. To install this driver package in Ubuntu 18.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-465 nvidia-settings
sudo reboot
```

In Ubuntu 20.04 and later, run these commands instead.

```
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers install 
sudo reboot
```

The `install` option of `ubuntu-drivers` installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies.